# Why can't logical subsets to a data.table use newly derived variables locally?

Tags: r, data.table

I am using `data.table` to perform subsets and create new variables. It's interesting to note that variables which existed when `data.table` can be called can be supplied as an expression, and `[.data.table` is smart enough to parse the expression like `subset`, using the `data.table` as the environment. I find that this doesn't work with variables *derived* in the `data.table`. For instance:

```
mydt <- data.table(i = -10:10)
mydt[i > 0] ## works:
mydt[, keep := i > 0]
mydt[keep] ## doesn't work
subset(mydt, keep) ## does work
```

Is this a bug or is there an option I am supposed to supply to `:=` to make this happen?

Comment: You're conflating two issues here.  Note that `mydt <- data.table(i = c(TRUE, FALSE)); mydt[i]` doesn't give what you apparently expect either.  It doesn't have anything to do with a variable being a derived expression.

Comment: try: mydt[keep == TRUE]

Comment: You can also do: `mydt[which(keep)]`

Comment: @Dason can you say more about why the first case works? I use this type of syntax often and want to be sure I'm not making a mistake.

Comment: mydt[(keep)] is the most concise approach. data.table enforces this to prevent mydt[keep] from being ambiguous. mydt[keep] is the syntax for a (keyed) join.

Comment: The first case is covered by "`i` [...] _expression_ of column names" (about `i` argument in `?data.table`)

Comment: "doesn't work" -- with an error that explains why it doesn't work, right?